# Simple Core Data application not able to read core data model keys

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data

I am trying to write a very simple Core Data OS X application.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Create a new Core Data application called `PortalMan`. This also created an `NSAppDelegate` called `PortalManAppDelegate`.
2. Go to the `PortalMan.xcdatamodeld` data model and create a new entity called `Repo` with three attributes: `active`, `branch`, `path`. `active` is a Boolean, the other two are Strings.
3. Open the interface editor for `MainMenu.xib`
4. Drag a new `NSArrayController` to the document space
5. On the Attributes tab of the `NSArrayController`, set the "Mode" to "Entity Name" and set the "Entity Name" attribute as "Repo"
6. Check the "Prepares Content" box
7. On the Bindings tab for the `NSArrayController`, select the Managed Object Context binding. Enable it, and bind it to the "Portal Man App Delegate".
8. Set "Model Key Path" to "managedObjectContext".
9. Drag a table view to the window
10. Add a column, and in its "Value" Binding, set "Bind To: Array Controller", set the "Controller Key" to "arrangedObjects" and the "Model Key Path" to "branch"

I also added a button and bound it to the Array Controller's `add` method.

When I try and run my application, I get this error:

```
2012-01-06 16:01:43.650 PortalMan[656:707] An uncaught exception was raised
2012-01-06 16:01:43.651 PortalMan[656:707] [<NSApplication 0x100401750> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key branch.
```

This makes me think it's not grabbing my Core Data "Repo" model appropriately, because "Repo" **does** have a "branch" attribute.

Any thoughts on this or how I can debug it?

Thanks!

Comment: Read the error message again: Repo may have a branch attribute, but the application object does not. You tried to get the branch of the application object, not a Repo, and that's why it failed.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally selected a "Content Array" binding at some point.

I removed that binding and everything works perfectly as I'd expect now.

Thanks! Hope this helps someone else. If you're having issues like this: **REVIEW ALL THE BINDINGS ON YOUR NSArrayController!**